# Angular handle only unhandled error responses

Tags: angular

I have a rather conceptional question about intercepting errors. My goal would be that there are several requests going to the backend, and some of them will be handled directly in the subscribe method of the request.

```
myHttpRequest.subscribe(() => success, () => error);
```

In this case, I want only error part to be executed. But if there is no error case, e.g.

```
myOtherHttpRequest.subscribe(() => success);
```

I want my http interceptor to handle it.

Is there a correct way to implement this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use catchError operator, an example of an interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError(error => {...})
  );
}
```

Comment: Yea I know that, but in that way all my HttpErrorResponses will be catched by the interceptor. I want my interceptor to catch errors only, when nothing else handled it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'HttpErrorResponses' and 'errors'?

Comment: They are the same, I just used other words for it.

Comment: catchError intercepts only errors, I don't understand what you want to do exactly.